# lseek sparse-file comparison with regular file resulting in unexpected results?

Tags: c, unix

From my understanding, i've been reading advanced unix programming book. Using lseek with a file and creating a hole should be use less disk space as the hole is not recorded on the disk and the hole is filled with zeros.

However i created two files one with a hole and one without, however the one without a hole uses less disk space, than the one with a hole. I think i may of messed up in the code, however i'm not sure how i ended up with these results. AS this seems to contradict of what i understand of file holes. And shouldn't the two files be off the same size?

I may be completely fundamentally missing the point of the usage of lseek? If so feel free to down vote, as i know only the highest quality of posts are allowed. And explain what I'm missing here? thanks.

**Code with lseek**

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

char buf1[] = "abcdefghik";
char buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int main (void)
{
    int fd;

    if((fd = creat("file.hole" , FILE_MODE)) < 0)
            err_sys("creat error");

    if(write(fd , buf1 , 10) != 10)
            err_sys("buf1 write error");

    //offset now = 10 becaues we wrote 10 bytes

    if(lseek(fd , 16384 , SEEK_SET) == -1)
            err_sys("lseek error");
    /*offset now = 16384 there is now a hole*/

    if(write(fd , buf2 , 10) != 10)
            err_sys("buf2 write error");
    /*offset now 16384 + 10 bytes = 16394*/

    exit(0);

//now have a gap in file, however this gap is not written to the disk. so doesn't take up all that space on the disk
}
```

**Code without lseek**

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

char buf1[] = "abcdefghij";
char buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int main (void){
    int fd;

    //creating new file
    if((fd = creat("file.nohole" , FILE_MODE)) < 0)
            err_sys("create error");

    //writing 10 bytes of buf1
    if(write(fd,buf1,10) != 10)
            err_sys("write buf1 error");
    //writing 10 bytes of buf2
    if(write(fd,buf2,10) != 10)
            err_sys("write buf2 error");

    exit(0);

    //no hole in the file.
}
```

**od -c file.hole (checking contents)**

```
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   k  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0040000   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0040012
```

**od -c file.nohole (checking contents)**

```
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   A   B   C   D   E   F
0000020   G   H   I   J
0000024
```

**comparing two files - ls -ls file.hole file.nohole**

```
28 -rw-r--r-- 1 sam sam 16394 Jul 10 14:09 file.hole
12 -rw-r--r-- 1 sam sam    20 Jul 10 14:32 file.nohole
```

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question, even if you are _"fundamentally missing the point of the usage of lseek"_.  The question is well asked, well formatted, understandable and there is a [mcve]. (However I don't have the answer either).

Comment: or use `du file*` to get the actual disk usage.

Comment: And for the record: sparse files are a filesystem feature (or at least can be), when using the lseek-code without sparse files support, the filesystem driver will have to create a file of that size writing 0-bytes to it (i.e. vfat).

Answer (score 1):

The file with the hole has data stored on two separate disk blocks.

The file with no hole has data stored on one disk block.

The size reported by `ls` is the number of bytes in the file, not the number of bytes stored in disk blocks.  The missing bytes are all zeros, as the output from `od -c` makes clear.

Note that the point of using `lseek()` is not to create holes in files.  Those are an implementation detail.  The reason to use `lseek()` is to place the read/write position in the file where you want to read from or write to next.  For example, in a file with fixed size records, you can get to the Nth record by using `lseek(fd, N * sizeof(struct Record), SEEK_SET)` and then read (or write) the data at that position.